# Simple Harmonic Motion of a Pendulum Derivation Questions

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, harmonic-oscillator

> A simple pendulum with mass m on a string of length l is released from rest at an angle of $\theta_0$ to the vertical.
>
> (i) Assuming that the pendulum undergoes simple harmonic motion, ﬁnd an expression for its angular displacement as a function of time; hence determine its speed as it passes through the equilibrium position.
>
> (ii) Using conservation of energy ﬁnd this speed exactly and show that the result is the same as in (i).

So, I equated $-mg \sin \theta$ and $ml\ddot{\theta}$ for the first part and then set $\sin \theta = \theta$ using the small angle approximation. I then used $\theta = \theta_0 \cos(kt)$ as a general solution and worked out $k$ as $\sqrt{g/l}$. Then I got the velocity as $\sqrt{g/l}\theta_0$ with this method but I'm pretty sure that's wrong as my max velocity for part (ii) was $\sqrt{2gl(1-\cos \theta)}$ from the $E_k$ and $E_p$ equations (so I assume $\sqrt{2gl}$ as $\max E_p/E_k$.

Can someone tell me where I went wrong, thanks.

Comment: I converted your expressions to MathJax (LaTeX code). Please use it next time in your questions, it makes them much more readable.

Comment: Check the units on your velocity formula. That will tell you something.